# I am trying to use a string to find the mass of a random thing, associating a letter to a mass

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am trying to do something where I associate specific letters to an specific mass, and use a string to identify how much something weight.

```
mass=0
p=0
s="ABAB"
while True:
    if s.find("A", p): 
          mass=mass+71
          p+=1
    elif  s.find("B", p):
          mass=mass+2
          p+=1
    else:
        break
print(f"{mass}")
```

In theory, I would expect this to happen:

p=0, which is "A", in the string, so the mass becomes 71

p=1, which is "B", in the string, so the mass becomes 73

p=2, which is "A", in the string, so the mass becomes 145

p=3, which is "B", in the string, so the mass becomes 147

p=4, Which is equal to "", and thus, should've close the while

So, what I wanted with this program was for it to analize the string and add the mass accordinly, until there was nothing else on it. However, this does not work at all. It just keeps going at infinite (like this: 71+71+71..), and ignoring the whole position of the string I was attempting to do.

How do I solve that?

Am i just using the s.find() wrong? If yes, what else should I use?

I am using the Python IDLE, if that's important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) are for -- you can map keys to values. Then just loop over and look them up:

```
s = "ABAB"

masses = {
    'A': 71,
    'B': 2
} 

# For each letter in s, lookup up the mass. 
# Take the sum of them all
total = sum(masses[c] for c in s)
# 146
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is the expectation that `str.find` returns `True/False`. In fact, `str.find` returns an integer which is the position where the substring was found, or - and this is the key - `-1`, when it doesn't find it.

Now, in your last iteration, `str.find` returns `-1` which **actually evaluates to Boolean True**, hence the loop never exits.

The better solutions is to check `str.find` results against `-1`, or use the solution with dictionaries as proposed by Mark Meyer.

The other issue is that `str.find` allows a `start` and `end` parameter, which are used as `slice`. This means that `str.find` will look for the substring (or character in your case) *not just at position `p`* but at the entire substring *starting at `p`*.

This leads to a double counting of `A` hence the wrong mass result.

To make it work as you expect, you would actually want to use both `start/end` parameters, and the resulting modified code would be like this:

```
mass=0
p=0
s="ABAB"

while True:
    if s.find("A", p, p+1) != -1:  # found at or after position p
          print("Found A", p)
          mass += 71
          p += 1

    elif  s.find("B", p, p+1) != -1:  # found at or after position p
          print("Found B", p)
          mass += 2
          p += 1

    else:
        break

print(f"{mass}")
```

This should explain the pitfalls with your current code.